# cakephp: fatal error: can't find core.php when configuring cakephp on shared webhost justhost.com

Tags: cakephp, configuration, shared, host

i've uploaded my website (to justhost.com) as per the instructions in Installation for Production server and Advanced Installation in the cakephp cookbook. I've also followed the guidance given in my previous post cakephp: configuring cakephp on shared host justhost. I've moved the config folder from app to webroot. However, i'm still getting :

```
Warning: include(/home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/config/core.php) 

[function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aquinto1/cake/libs/configure.php on line 400

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/config/core.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/aquinto1:/home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/aquinto1/cake/libs/configure.php on line 400

Fatal error: Can't find application core file. Please create /home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/config/core.php, and make sure it is readable by PHP. in /home/aquinto1/cake/libs/configure.php on line 401
```

Can someone point out on what mistake i'm making. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you move the config folder to webroot? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: because of the Fatal error. The error says core.php is not in /home/aquinto1/public_html/merryflowers.com/config/. I also tried creating a config folder and moved core.php to that folder within ../public_html/merryflowers.com/ without touching the ../app/config but that work too. I still got the same errors as in my question above.

Comment: i also tried setting the permissions of /app/tmp folder, /app/tmp/cache and all the files and folders within cache ie. models, persistent and views to 777 from the justhost file manager but that didn't work either. I still keep getting the same warnings and fatal error.

Comment: Is your core.php file in fact in the place where Cake is looking for it? Also, setting your cache folders to 777 won't help much if your config folder is unreadable. You'd have to do that to your config folder.

Comment: i deleted everything on the remote server and uploaded everything all over again. Now i'm getting 500 internal server error. Now, core.php is in /app/config/. I only have the views and webroot in /public_html/merryflowers.com/.

Comment: Joep, i notice that /app/config is readable by all.

Comment: Only the content of the webroot folder has to be in public_html/merryflowers.com/, everything else can be somewhere else. Make sure you adapt the index.php file from the webroot folder accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the Cake folder at all, then you have up update web root/index.php and tell it where to find the lib directory.  These steps are a little different between 1.3 and 2.0+, so I am assuming 2.0 here.

Open webroot/index.php and find `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');`.  Uncomment it and change `ROOT . DS . 'lib'` to the path of the lib folder under webroot.  It would probably look like this:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'lib');
```

This tells cake to look for the lib folder in app/webroot.

This all said, don't put the lib folder in web root because that would be web accessible. Put it in the app folder instead and make sure that the include path points to the right dir.

Answer (score 0):

As dhofstet said, i had put only the contents of webroot in /public_html/merryflowers.com/.

I have edited index.php in /public_html/merryflowers.com/ as follows:

```
/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */

if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS.'aquinto1');  
    //define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR','app');
    //define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS.'home'.DS.'aquinto1');

}
```

The static pages of the website is displaying now! :)

Scott Harwell, i'm using cakephp 1.3.

Thank you all for the guidance. You guys are just amazing! :)